# how packed decimal stores values. how to write a node js logic for packed decimal of variable type PIC S9(09)V99 COMP-3

Tags: node.js, node-modules, binaryfiles, cobol, binary-data

I have a variables of type PIC S9(09)V99 COMP-3 and PIC S9(07) COMP-3 in a file. I need to parse it and get the value in node js. Could you please help me understand it with simple examples. Also help me understand how data is stored for the same

Comment: Those formats are documented, no? (Isn't it COBOL BCD stuff?) So simple byte manipulation depending on which specific format it is should be sufficient. What specific issue are you having?

Comment: using node js i am unable to unpack the packed decimal values of PIC S9(09)V99 COMP-3/ Not able able to find code logic to it.

Comment: Can you be more specific? IIRC it's bytes packed in BCD so each byte has two BCD numbers. I don't recall the specifics--showing what you have tried, the expected output, and actual output, would be helpful.

Comment: Packed decimal is just as @DaveNewton describes: +123 is stored as x'123C', -123 is stored as x'123D'.  Caveat: the sign nybble can be C, A, F, E for positive and B or D for negative.  IBM uses the term "preferred sign" for C as positive and D as negative.

Comment: @cschneid I knew another oldbie would have the details :)

Comment: Please keep in mind that for files containing COMP or COMP-3 fields you must under no circumstances apply any sort of charset conversion. So be prepared to handle the alphanumeric fields in EBCDIC as well...

Comment: When i am parsing my binary file using node js for the variable "PIC S9(09)V99 COMP-3" is giving me '\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0002\f' instead of decimal  and variable "PIC S9(07) COMP-3" is giving me  '\u0000\u0000\u0000\f'

Answer (score 0):

Cobol natural way of working with number is Binary coded decimal a.k.a BCD.

1. "Classic" PIC (USAGE IS DISPLAY)

   **THEORY :**

   When you write PIC S9(4)V9(3) with a `USAGE` value of `DISPLAY`, that is to say without writing COMP-3, it is BCD.

   In this way of writing number, a digit takes one octet (i.e. 8 bits) to be stored.
   Each octet can be divided in two quartet, also know as nibble. A quartet is a group of 4 bits. So writing a digit takes two quartet, that is to say 2*4 bits which adds up to 8 bits = 1 octet.

   When writing a digit the first quartet will hold a value wich represent the sign carried by the digit. The only digit that carry the sign is the last. The positive value is C (like credit) in hexadecimal and 1100 in binary. The negative is D (like Debit) in hexadecimal and 1101 in binary. The neutral letter is F in hex and 1111 in binary.

   The second quartet will hold the binary value for your digit. For instance if my digit is 7, the quartet will be 0111.

   **EXAMPLE :**

   If I take the example I have written above PIC S9(4)V9(3), it has 4 + 3 = 7 digits. It needs 7 octets to be stored. Let's say that I want to store the number +0036.421

   then the 7 octets would be 0033421

   - First digit 0  : 1111 0000 ; which in Hex is : F0
   - Second digit 0 : 1111 0000 ; which in Hex is : F0
   - Third digit 3 : 1111 0011 ; which in Hew is : F3
   - Fourth digit 6 : 1111 0110 ; which in Hex is : F6
   - Fifth digit 4 : 1111 0100 ; which in Hex is : F4
   - Sixth digit 2 : 1111 0010 ; which in Hex is : F2
   - Seventh digit 1 : 1100 0001 ; which in Hex is : C1. This digit carrie the sign for the whole number. The first quartet is C, because the number is positive.
2. COMP-3 PIC (Packed decimal)

   **THEORY :** 
   As you can see you takes up a lot of space (7 octets !!!) for writing a rather small number. for comparisons, in binary with seven octets you can store 2^56 values !
   So in order to keep some memory there is another format, the packed decimal, which you can use by adding COMP-3 to your declaration.

   In this format instead of storing a digit in a whole octet, you just take a quartet. The trick is not to store the signs for the digits that aren't the last digit. Because as you can see above, most of the quartet just have a F value for the first quartet which convey little to no information.

   The last quartet of the last octet contains the sign of the whole number. Therefore if we have n digits, we need n+1 quartets to store the number in packed decimal. So the space occupied by a number with n digits in packed decimal would be foor((n+1)/2). That is to say the lowest number of octet that contains n+1 quartet.

   **EXAMPLE :**
   My pic is 7 digits long, so I need 7+1=8 quartet = 4 octet.

   - First octet : 0000 0000 ; which is 00 in Hex (The first digit is 0, the second digit is 0)
   - Second Octet : 0011 0110 ; wich is 36 in Hex ( the third digit is 3, the fourth is 6)
   - Third Octet : 0100 0010 ; which is 42 in Hex ( the fifth digit is 4, the sixth is 2)
   - Fourth octet : 0001 1100 ; which is 1C in Hex ( the seventh digit is 1 and the sign of the whole number is +)

Comment: When i am parsing my binary file PIC S9(09)V99 COMP-3  is giving me  '\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0002\f' instead of decimal value

Comment: @user2454202 I don't really know how these type of files are encoded in Unicode. On mainframes they are encoded in EBCDIC. The thing that is happening is that JavaScript is showing you the string value that's encoded in unicode from the hexadecimals value of the file.From what I gather \u0000 is how JS represents the nul value in unicode which is 00 in hexadecimal (first octet so value of the first and second quarter). \u0002 is the start of text in unicode which translate to 02 in hex. And \f is form feed which makes 0C in hex. So in hexadecimal your string is +000000000,20

Comment: @user2454202 What you should do is find/write a function that translates the string character in its hexadecimal value and work with that :)